# Uploading and downloading files from Azure to Windows using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am writing a PowerShell script to communicate with my Microsoft Azure account, and I am facing an issue with uploading and downloading files using the Set-AzureStorageBlobContent and Get-AzureStorageBlobContent modules.

```
$Upload = @{
    Context = $storageContext;
    Container = $container;
    File = "C:\... \file.csv";
    }
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent @Upload -Force;
```

The first time I run this, it appears to start uploading, but it stays at 0% and never rises. If I cancel it and try executing my script again, I get an error that says:
"Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : A transfer operation with the same source and destination already exists."
A nearly identical thing happens when I try to download an existing blob from Azure.

```
$params = @{
    Context = $storageContext;
    Container = $container;
    Blob = $blob;
    Destination = $dest
    }
New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory -Force
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent @params
```

I have tried reinstalling Azure.Storage, which is the module that contains the cmdlet Get-AzureStorageBlobContent and Set-AzureStorageBlobContent, but I had no luck. Am I doing something incorrectly, or is this code just wrong somehow?

Comment: Sounds likely to be a security setting: possibly?

Comment: I think you may be right. I tried changing the execution policy to bypass while I was running the script (from unrestricted), and it worked. That is, >> powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\..."

Comment: What is the output from `Get-ExecutionPolicy`?

Comment: For me, Get-ExecutionPolicy gives me unrestricted because that is what I set it to be using Set-ExecutionPolicy. However, the scope of the the command I mentioned earlier is just for that one execution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something with your $Upload variable. Try this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path C:\Images\* | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "yourcontainername"
```

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-powershell-guide-full